# Bug on /review already closed

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

On the cast close vote page, this came up:
[image]

No potential close reason listed, and its already shown as closed. Any ideas what happened, or is this to be expected?

question link: https://superuser.com/questions/602211/work-and-play-how-would-i-setup-connecting-to-a-github-account-for-personal-pro
review link: https://superuser.com/review/close/123039

This was a test. Is it supposed to be that obvious?

Comment: probably an artifact of the on-hold updates edit: simiilar on MSO: [Audit has shown too much detail about the post making the audit obvious](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185982)

Answer (score 2):

This has been resolved, take a look this meta post: [Getting what appear to be reopen audits in close vote queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188661/getting-what-appear-to-be-reopen-audits-in-close-vote-queue)